# MariaDB replication using salt - state not found

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, fedora, salt-stack

I'm trying to setup a replica of a running MariaDB instance using salt. Here is my code:

```
{% if pillar.get('REPLICATION_SOURCE_IP') and pillar.get('REPLICATION_SOURCE_PORT') %}

replication-set-gtid:
  mysql_query.run:
  - database: mysql
  - query: |
      set @MY_GTID_EXEC = @@GLOBAL.GTID_EXECUTED;
      RESET MASTER;
      set GLOBAL GTID_PURGED = @MY_GTID_EXEC;

replication-connect-to-master:
  mysql_query.run:
  - database: mysql
  - query: |
      CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='{{pillar['REPLICATION_SOURCE_IP']}}',
      MASTER_PORT={{pillar['REPLICATION_SOURCE_PORT']}},
      MASTER_USER='{{pillar['REPLICATION_REPLICA_USERNAME']}}',
      MASTER_PASSWORD='{{pillar['REPLICATION_REPLICA_PASSWORD']}}',
      MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1,
      MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=15

replication-start-replica:
  mysql_query.run:
  - database: mysql
  - query: "START SLAVE"

wait-for-slave:
  cmd.run:
  - name: until [[ $(mysql -P {{pillar['PORT']}} -e "show global status like 'slave_running'" mysql | grep 'Slave_running' | cut -f 2) == 'ON' ]]; do sleep 1; done

{% endif %}
```

I'm getting the following error from the salt minion logs:

```
[ERROR   ] State 'mysql_query.run' was not found in SLS 'mariadb-10_1_00-replication-prepare-replica'
Reason: 'mysql_query' __virtual__ returned False
```

The MariaDB image I'm using contains these dependencies:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-client -y
sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel -y
sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
sudo yum -y install python-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this Salt problem. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using the wrong pip package. On my system I don't have `MySQL-python`, I just have (you may need only one of them):

```
mysqlclient==1.3.7
PyMySQL==0.7.2
```

On Ubuntu 16.04, they are installed from the packages:

```
ii  python-mysqldb                     1.3.7-1build2                                            
ii  python-pymysql                     0.7.2-1ubuntu1
```

I think you can find similar packages in Fedora as well, without having to install them via pip